# Converting str object of list to one list object

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
[['Yar\\u0131n'], ',', ['Mehmet'], 'ile', 'birlikte', ["Ankara'da", 'ki', 'Nufus', "Mudurlugu'ne"], ',', ['Aziz', 'Y\\u0131ld\\u0131r\\u0131m'], 'ile', 'birlikte', ',', ['Sukru', 'Saracoglu', "Stad\\u0131'na"], 'gidecegiz', '.']
```

Is there a way to make all of my list elements one list object?

I want my list like this:

```
[['Yar\\u0131n'], [','], ['Mehmet'], ['ile'], ['birlikte'], ["Ankara'da", 'ki','Nufus', "Mudurlugu'ne"], [','], ['Aziz', 'Y\\u0131ld\\u0131r\\u0131m'], ['ile'], 'birlikte', ',', ['Sukru', 'Saracoglu', "Stad\\u0131'na"], 'gidecegiz', '.']
```

Also it would be so useful to overcome these non-ascii characters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
>>> l = [['Yar\\u0131n'], ',', ['Mehmet'], 'ile', 'birlikte', ["Ankara'da", 'ki', 'Nufus', "Mudurlugu'ne"], ',', ['Aziz', 'Y\\u0131ld\\u0131r\\u0131m'], 'ile', 'birlikte', ',', ['Sukru', 'Saracoglu', "Stad\\u0131'na"], 'gidecegiz', '.']
>>> [[item] if not isinstance(item, list) else item for item in l]
[['Yar\\u0131n'], [','], ['Mehmet'], ['ile'], ['birlikte'], 
 ["Ankara'da", 'ki', 'Nufus', "Mudurlugu'ne"], [','], 
 ['Aziz', 'Y\\u0131ld\\u0131r\\u0131m'], ['ile'], ['birlikte'], [','], 
 ['Sukru', 'Saracoglu', "Stad\\u0131'na"], ['gidecegiz'], ['.']]
```

Comment: god bless you @alecxe